# Orientdb referencing table property in geo function

Tags: graph, orientdb

I want to refer to a class property called Distance in my class Location to set the maxDistance value within the NEAR geo function. How do i refer to a class property within the near clause?

I want to this to happen at run time.

The below returns blank even though there is an entry in Location with a distance value of 1 and lat and long coords that within that distance.

orientdb 2.0.12

```
select *, $distance as distance from Location where [latitude,longitude,$spatial] NEAR [51.5102451,-0.1320087000000285,{"maxDistance": distance}]
```

Above: Does not return a value

```
select *, $distance as distance from Location where [latitude,longitude,$spatial] NEAR [51.5102451,-0.1320087000000285,{"maxDistance": 1}]
```

Above: Returns a value

Answer (score 0):

You cannot

$distance is a projection that the near operator put in the results set.

You cannot use this to filter in maxDistance since is not resolved yet.

Comment: distance a class property on the class location. its a field i have defined with a value. I am looking to to set Lat,Long,Distance on the location and check then to see if another set of coords is within that distance. distance is just the property name i chose to hold the maxdistance i want to check for